# android ndk-gdb "watchdog timeout has expired"

Tags: android-ndk

After debugging an Android native app for ~10 minutes I get:

```
"Watchdog timeout has expired. Target detached."
```

and my app terminates.  I have a random crash that seems to occur after ~40 minutes (although unpredictable)...does anyone know how to allow ndk-gdb to run longer? Or any other suggestions?

Comment: The first suggestion would be to analyze the crash logs, and even if it does not pinpoint the actual reason, you have a good chance to find some common pattern, and look for crash less unpredictable. Second, you can wait for ~35 minutes and launch **ndk-gdb** only then. By default, if you don't specify `--start` argument, it will attach to the running process, and you have a good chance to survive the timeout until a crash happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Unfortunately I have already analyzed the crash logs and the reason I need gdb is that I want to see what the other threads are doing at the time of the crash.  I also tried the strategy of waiting ~35 minutes and attaching the debugger...but alas it didn't crash (as I mentioned it's unpredictable).

Comment: I get that, too.  It's annoying.  I don't who decided to put a watchdog (and disconnects) into a debugging package.  It's like a trial version or something... opensource software... no common sense.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Maintenance-Commands.html

```
set watchdog nsec
    Set the maximum number of seconds gdb will wait for the target operation
    to finish. If this time expires, gdb reports and error and the command is aborted. 

show watchdog
    Show the current setting of the target wait timeout.
```

I set the time to `set watchdog 32000000`